# What are some strategies for loading files with uneven columns through SSIS?

Tags: ssis, etl

I need to load a pipe delimited file into a database using SSIS. The file contains detail rows with over 100 columns, and summary rows with 13 columns. What is the best way to accomplish this? I write a script that “squares” the file by adding delimiters to the summary rows. But the file is around 20 MB, and thus takes a long time to run.

Answer (score 0):

I've accomplished one such problem where we had to extract info from pipe separated columns(30 pipes). I ended up creating a `stg` table with 30 columns. SSIS used to map empty/non-empty values in this stg table and further tasks were used to drive ahead, once we have data in those 30 columns.